# How to batch matrix-vector multiplication (one matrix, many vectors) in pytorch without duplicating the matrix in memory

Tags: python, pytorch

I have `n` vectors of size `d` and a single `d x d` matrix `J`. I'd like to compute the `n` matrix-vector multiplications of `J` with each of the `n` vectors.

For this, I'm using pytorch's `expand()` to get a *broadcast* of `J`, but it seems that when computing the matrix vector product, pytorch instantiates a full `n x d x d` tensor in the memory. e.g. the following code

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
n = 100_000_000
d = 10

x = torch.randn(n, d, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
J = torch.randn(d, d, dtype=torch.float32, device=device).expand(n, d, d)
y = torch.sign(torch.matmul(J, x[..., None])[..., 0])
```

raises

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 37.25 GiB (GPU 0; 11.00 GiB total capacity; 3.73 GiB already allocated; 5.69 GiB free; 3.73 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

which means that pytorch, unnecessarily, tries to allocate space for `n` copies of the matrix `J`

How can I perform this task in a vectorized way (the matrices are small, so I don't want to loop over each matrix-vector multiplication) without exhausting my GPU's memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will solve it:

```py
import torch
x = torch.randn(n, d)
J = torch.randn(d, d) # no need to expand

y = torch.matmul(J, x.T).T
```

Verifying using your expression:

```py
Jex = J.expand(n, d, d)
y1 = torch.matmul(Jex, x[..., None])[..., 0]
y = torch.matmul(J, x.T).T

torch.allclose(y1, y) # using allclose for float values
# tensor(True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Followup question: The idiom you gave will not give the the correct answer if J really is composed of n different matrices while the original one is correct for both cases (multiplying all n vectors by the same matrix or by n different ones). Is there a way to have this feature as well without broadcasting?

Comment: One alternative is `torch.matmul(J, x[..., None]).squeeze(-1)`, though you have to broadcast `x` here to perform a batch matrix vector multiplication. I am assuming `J` is of shape _n x d x d_ and `x` of _n x d_. The matmul returns a tensor of shape _n x d x 1_, that's why I added a `squeeze()` to remove the redundant last dimension.

Comment: Also note that in the above expression, no transpose is necessary since we are making a compatible batched matrix vector multiplication between tensors of shape _n x d x d_ and _n x d x 1_(shape of `x[..., None]`). It all boils down to how you pass your tensors to the `matmul` function.

Comment: I just realized `torch.matmul(J, x[..., None]).squeeze(-1)` is exactly what you did in the question! Ha ha, I guess broadcasting is inevitable here for `x`! Or you can ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a solution:

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(n, d)

J = torch.randn(d, d) 

y = torch.einsum('ij,bj->bi', J, x)  # y.shape -> (n,d)
```